# actionscript full screen not allowed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This is my code to add the button onto stage

```
private function add_fullScreenBtn(height:Number):void
{

    button_fullScr = new Sprite();
    button_fullScr.useHandCursor = true;
    button_fullScr.buttonMode = true;
    button_fullScr.mouseChildren = false;

    button_fullScr.x = height;
    button_fullScr.y = btn_y;

    var fullScr_Btn:Bitmap = new fullScreenImage();
    button_fullScr.addChild(fullScr_Btn);        
    button_fullScr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreenHandler);
    addChild(button_fullScr);

}
```

This is the code for handling the event when the user clicks on fullscreen button

```
private function fullScreenHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Here");
   // stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
    if (this.stage.displayState== StageDisplayState.NORMAL) {
        //stage.displayState="fullScreen";
        this.stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    } else {
        //stage.displayState="normal";
        this.stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }
}
```

This is the code of html page

```
 <html>
      <head>This is the Test Page    
      </head>
      <body>
     <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 
       codebase="http://.../swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" 
       width="550" height="400" id="sample" align="middle">      
       <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />      
       <param name="movie" value="sample.swf" />
       <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="bgcolor" value="#333333" />
       <embed src="sample.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#333333" 
           width="550" height="400" 
           name="sample" align="middle" 
           allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" 
           type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
           allowFullScreen="true" 
           pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
      </embed>
    </object>

      </body>
    </html>
```

When I am running this page I am getting error that full screen mode is not allowed. security exception. When I am tracing it on console its printing "here"

can anyone suggest how can i solve the error

Comment: Is this html the only one? There is usually static html and also the one generated by javascript -- check its parameters.

Comment: this is one is static html.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the line to scale the image i.e i added the following line

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

before

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

and it worked